# Need help displaying a dynamic table

Tags: php, mysql

I am designing a job rota planner for a company and need help displaying a dynamic table containing the staff details. I have the following tables in MySQL database: Staff, Event, and Job. The staff table holds staff details (staffed, name, address...etc), the Event table (eventide, eventName, Fromdate, Todate...etc) and the Job table holds (Jobid, Jobdate, Eventid(fk), Staffid (fk)). 
I need to dynamically display the available staff list from the staff table when the user selects the EVENT and the DATE (3 drop downs: date, month, and year) from a PHP form. 
I need to display staff members that have not been assigned work on the selected date by checking the Jobdate in the Job table.
I have been at this for all day and can't get around it. I am still learning PHP and would surely appreciate any help I can get. 
My current code displays all staff members when an event is selected:

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 { 
$eventId = $_POST['eventradio'];

 }
 $timePeriod = $_POST['timeperiod'];
 $Day = $_POST['day'];
 $Month = $_POST['month'];      
 $Year = $_POST['year'];
 $dateValue = $Year."-".$Month."-".$Day;
 $selectedDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateValue));

//construct the available staff list
if ($selectedDate)
    {
        $staffsql = "SELECT s.StaffId, s.LastName, s.FirstName
        FROM Staff s 
        WHERE s.StaffId NOT IN
        (SELECT J.StaffId
        FROM Job J
        WHERE J.JobDate = ".$selectedDate.")";
        $staffResult = mysql_query($staffsql) or die (mysql_error());

    }
if ($staffResult){
    echo "<p><table cellspacing='1' cellpadding='3'>";
    echo "<th colspan=6>List of Available Staff</th>";
    echo "</tr><tr><th> Select</th><th>Id</th><th></th><th>Last Name
        </th><th></th><th>First Name </th></tr>";

    while ($staffarray = mysql_fetch_array($staffResult))
    {
        echo "<tr onMouseOver= this.bgColor = 'red' onMouseOut =this.bgColor = 'white' bgcolor= 
            '#FFFFFF'> <td align=center><input type='checkbox' name='selectbox[]'
            id='selectbox[]' value=".$staffarray['StaffId'].">
            </td><td align=left>".$staffarray['StaffId']."
            </td><td>&nbsp&nbsp</td><td align=center>".$staffarray['LastName']."
            </td><td>&nbsp&nbsp</td><td align=center>".$staffarray['FirstName']."
            </td></tr>";
    }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br> The Staff list can not be displayed!";
    }       
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td></td>";
    echo "<td align=center><input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Assign Staff'>&nbsp&nbsp";
    echo "<input type='reset' value='Start Over'>";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 1 of 2 things.

a.) add an onchange event to your select list and make an AJAX call to your server to pull back the table data, or

b.) add an onchange event to your select list and submit the form/page to itself (thus including the value selected from the select list

In your PHP (either way) using the parameter on the request (if it exists) load the applicable data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using PHP throughout...so the second option seems suitable. I'm thinking on using a submit button to confirm drop down date like this:
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (($_POST['day']) && ($_POST['month']) && ($_POST['year'])) {
//run the select query
}
?>
Not sure if this's right and not sure about the sql query either. I'm kind of new for this...
Thanks again!

Comment: The best query would be with the MINUS function but MySQL does not support that. So I've tried Not In function as above but it only works in some cases....please help! Thanks a bunch!